# Configuring Nginx to support PHP on Mac OS X

Tags: php, angularjs, macos, nginx

I am building a web site using Angular JS, hosted on my local system using nginx. I want to add a contact form to my web site, but I don't know how to configure my nginx.conf file to support php. My nginx.conf server section has some lines involving php:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

I uncommented this but that's not working. What all do I need to do? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Off-Topic: this question is better asked on Server Fault rather than here. This site is dedicated to programming, ie problems with the code you want to run on your web server when it is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that param SCRIPT_FILENAME is incorrect.
Change it to `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`